# Calling stored procedure in jdbc

Tags: java, android, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am developing android application. And i am using sql sever 2008 database to store and retrieve the data. Now i am calling the stored procedure in jbdc. [Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/GiAZCNL0). Now it gives me Exception which says Invalid Column Index at 3. I am using the same code in other place which works fine. Bt don't know why nt working here. Give proper advice if you have any idea. Thank You.

I just found out that when the  String dat = rs.getString(3); is executing it shows the above exception. Let me tell you that in stored procedures it was datetime. But it executes well. Any suggestions do help me.

[Here is the stored Procedure](http://pastebin.com/dy47R8JC)

Comment: Full stacktrace would probably help understanding the problem

Comment: May i know what is stacktrace?

Comment: http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010009

Comment: My guess, though, is that the problem is coming from stored procedure, not from Java code.

Comment: Please paste the definition of your stored procedure. Parameter #3 is likely not to be an IN/OUT parameter...

Comment: I have post a link of stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your java code, it would appear that your parameters are either OUT or INOUT params. If that is the case, you probably need to register them as such, so you can get data from them.

eg

```
cst.setInt(1,userId);
cst.setLong(2,taskId);
cst.setString(3, date);

cst.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
cst.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMERIC);
cst.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);

rs = cst.executeQuery();
```

Hopefully, that should fix your problem.